# RecyclerView with Horizontal GridLayoutManager and PageIndicator

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am relatively new to android and stuck on this particular implementation.

How do i implement a View(`RecyclerView`) with Horizontal `GridLayoutManager`(3*5) along with `PageIndicator` so basically 1st page would show 15 images, swiping left would show another 15(`PageIndicator` would change color) and so on.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Since you're new to programming you must have used Google to search what you want, right? What did you find and why did those solutions not work for you?

Comment: Please explain better what you want to achieve. As @ZUNJAE said, add some references at the code you used.

Comment: Please provide some code so that it helps us solve your issues. Without your code, even we here are sitting ducks.

Comment: https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html here is the examples you have to manipulate  as you want..

Answer (score 0):

you used viewpagerand set recycler view in viewpager or gridview. viewpager to handle swipe and easy. and you give it pageindictor in viewpager it's implement is easy.

you use recycler view in you give left is hard and you do use pagination so it's implemention is hard

Answer (score 0):

It's frustrating when you are been downvoted, and i understand that, hence i tried to implement this myself and the implementation details can be found here
[Adjust Items inside recycler view + orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014041/adjust-items-inside-recycler-view-orientation-changes).